# Python: How to POST a .bin file

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python program to HTTP POST a file in order to upgrade a DD WRT router's firmware.

I can't believe how difficult it has been.

I have tried library after library: Requests, URLlib, Mechanize, Poster, etc

All I want to do is submit this form with one input (erase=0) and the ddwrt-upgrade-file.bin!

Also, Basic Auth is required.

Can anyone help me out here

Here is a capture from fiddler of the WORKING POST that I submitted myself using Chrome:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryHUneA7LUTBBT3Jfn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit_button"

    Upgrade
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryHUneA7LUTBBT3Jfn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="action"


    ------WebKitFormBoundaryHUneA7LUTBBT3Jfn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="change_action"


    ------WebKitFormBoundaryHUneA7LUTBBT3Jfn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit_type"


    ------WebKitFormBoundaryHUneA7LUTBBT3Jfn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="erase"

    0
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryHUneA7LUTBBT3Jfn
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dd-wrt-webupgrade_public_vga.bin"
    Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```